# Where I get the Live AppID for Paypal Api? I use adaptiveaccounts-sdk-php 3.6.106

Tags: php, paypal

The error is: "The X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID header contains an invalid value"

I'm trying user GetVerifiedStatusRequest() but, before, I need create Configuration objet. I have this like:

```
class Configuration
{
    public static function getConfig()
    {
        $config = array(
                "mode" => "live"
        );
        return $config;
    }

    public static function getAcctAndConfig()
    {
        $config = array(
                // Signature Credential
                "acct1.UserName" => "psssssssssssscom",
                "acct1.Password" => "K4AsssssssssBV3N",
                "acct1.Signature" => "AfzZ6gssssszfWjZXnEFQC6RA-Cssss9Qf6a.773ScU",

                "acct1.AppId" => "APP-80W284485P519543T",   // for sandbox
                );

        return array_merge($config, self::getConfig());;
    }
}
```

When I use AppId for sandbow, work fine. But, I can't find the LIVE APPID for my application. This is a old option? If its the case: Where can I get this value?

In "View or Remove API Signature" just have "API Username", "API Password" and "Signature".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply for an adaptive payments application by logging to **"[apps.paypal.com](http://apps.paypal.com)"** using your PayPal credentials .

Apart from filling out all the required information on the application page , you just need to select "GetVerifiedStatus" API under the "Adaptive Payments" . Since you want to use only "GetVerifiedStatus" API , your application should get approved automatically after submission and you will see your live APP ID on the same page .

Comment: Yes! It was "Approved Automatically". Regards!